# tried to npm link and run the package after but throws an error "no such file"

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-link

i did an `npm link` to my node package for generating password. however, after `npm link` and it throws these error:

> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/valeryfun/package.json'

> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/valeryfun/package.json'

i've included bin and repository type, but i still cant run the package.

here's the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "password-generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A password generator",
  "main": "index.js",
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": {
    "password-generator": "./index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Valery",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^4.1.1",
    "clipboardy": "^2.3.0",
    "commander": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/valeryfun/password-generator-lazy.git"
  }
}
```

did i miss out anything such that I couldn't use the package after linking it?

Comment: check this documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link . LOok at the example how it shows. have you tried like that same way ?

Comment: hi! yes i did follow the examples. @DivyanshuSah